# Typehint (intellisense) objects within a twig loop

Tags: symfony, twig, phpstorm

I've searched for a solution but I can't find any suitable for Twig, I know it's a quality of life thing. But it would make templating slightly easier.

**Example**

```
{% for userObj in userObjCollection %}
  {{ userObj.property }} 
  {# I want to type hint userObj so I can use intellisense to get the right property #}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm currently using the PHPStorm IDE,
any suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Note that this is pure a question for an easier way to code within the loop. Not something a user of a site would come in contact with. (Also added phpstorm tag to clarify)

**Edit 2**
I've got the Symfony2 and PHP Annotations plugins installed (Sorry for not pointing this out earlier)

Comment: In most IDE's you've got intellisense (when you start typing it automatically gives you the list of properties for the object) Normally I would use /** @var User[] $userObjCollection */ if I'd wanted such hinting in PHPStorm with a php loop. So it's not an autocomplete for the field itself but for properties of the object whilst coding.

Comment: OK, I understood now. Unfortunatelly I can't help you.

Comment: Are you using the symfony 2 plugin for phpstorm ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use this in your twig:

```
{# @var foo \FooObject #}
```

Comment: Please note for array / loop support use: `{# @var foo \FooObject[] #}`

Comment: For those of you who are unfamiliar with the Symfony plugin for PhpStorm, please note that it must be installed (via Preferences > Plugins) AND manually enabled at the project level (via Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Symfony > Enable Plugin for this Project).

Comment: I installed and enabled the plugin  but I still don't get any completion at all. Seems to recognize what the object should be and complete the variable name but hitting dot shows none of its properties.

Comment: @Nate I could kiss you! This was the problem! it was not enabled... man I wasted time for this...

Comment: And don't forget your file should have the extension .html.twig

Answer (score 7):

Personally I use the [Symfony Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=idea) plugin for PhpStorm, it has auto-complete for twig objects and even repositories.

Comment: Same here, its awesome. Some of the things it does (like type hinting in twig) are borderline magic! There's a PHP Annotations plugin that you may find useful too as it offers completion for all the Annotations also used by Symfony (@ORM etc..)

Comment: I've got them both and totally agree with you that it's pure awesome. But it doesn't seem to help me hint objects within loops, does it work for you guys? If so then it might be a misconfiguration on my side.

Comment: Don't know if you have already figured this out yet but if you use the @return hint with say ObjectType[] it will assume you are getting an array of ObjectType back and will work within foreach :-)